# Availability Group and Transfer SQL Server Objects SSIS task

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, ssis

We have two db instances on Always On Availability Group.

And I need to transfer data from selection of tables to the primary DB.

I have created SQL Agent Job for SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects for set of tables.

It was working very well except that after some number of executions the job crashes with non informative communicate: "...The package execution failed.  The step failed." Once the target server crashed, and also the AG configuration had to be readded. And second time the target DB is freezed on "Synchronizing" state and all subsequent runs fail.

1. Is this recommended configuration?
2. How can I trouble shoot it? I dodn't find anything in event viewer nor in Management Studio. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You'll need to look at the jobstep output in the history tables or use the job history GUI item and expand out the jobstep to see the information in the bottom panel. Without a more concise error, it's hard to say.

Comment: So in general this config is acceptable?

Comment: Assuming the connection in the package points to the listener, it should work, at least to connect...

Comment: Yes it worked for 20 times in a row, yet it broke with non informative error. (Package failed) do you know where I can look for the logs?

Comment: I'll refer you to my first comment to find more information for the jobstep.